# Why error AdvertisingIdClient error when added new places sdk

Tags: android, api, gradle, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

i got error AdvertisingIdClient when i add some new sdk places

here is my library 
// Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0"

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

error: package com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Modify app/build.gradle to add following dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
```